# How can I modify a function within a package?

Tags: r, function

I'm using the soundecology package in R Studio, and I would like to modify the multiple_sounds function so that it performs multiple sound indices analyses per file and includes the results of each indices analysis in one .csv.

The original code is this:

```
library(soundecology)
multiple_sounds(directory = "C:/Users/PhD/Analysis/NU Soundscapes/Test Set",
                resultfile = "C:/Users/PhD/Analysis/NU Soundscapes/ACIresults.csv",
                soundindex = "acoustic_complexity", no_cores = "max")
multiple_sounds(directory = "C:/Users/PhD/Analysis/NU Soundscapes/Test Set",
                resultfile = "C:/Users/PhD/Analysis/NU Soundscapes/ADIresults.csv",
                soundindex = "acoustic_diversity", db_threshold = -50, no_cores = "max")
```

I would like to modify the soundindex function to include both "acoustic_complexity" and "acoustic _diversity", so that I only need to perform the one multiple_sounds analysis and the results are all presented in one .csv spreadsheet. 
Thanks!

Comment: assignInNamespace

Comment: You may obtain the source code for this function, and then define your own function based on it.

Comment: See source code of [`multiple_sounds` function](https://github.com/ljvillanueva/soundecology/blob/master/soundecology/R/multiple_sounds.R) on GitHub. Actually it seems you can pass multiple items in *soundindex* argument.

Comment: The usual method would be to define the function as generic and then write a version for your class of object.